# Combining Regex

Tags: php, regex

I currently have 2 Regular expressions that I am trying to combine but I don't know how since I'm a little new to all this: `.*\Q%s\E.*` and  `^(.*?),`

So basically given a string I want to treat the quotes as literals and get all characters of the string up until a comma appears.

Comment: Please, provide some samples of what should be a valid string and what should be an invalid string

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What are "literal quotes"?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you want. Is it possible to edit your post with an exemple ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to use regex for this. There is a simpler way, using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

You will get an array of each string broken up at the comma. If there are no commas, then you will get an array with only one value, the string. It is hard to input this example into your code, as there is none, so here it is:

`$results = explode( ",", "testing this , string" )`

Will return this:

```html
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "testing this "
  [1]=>
  string(7) " string"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide a little more information as far as some examples of strings that would be parsed, I can edit this answer a little further. But for example purposes if you had a string such as:

`This is a "quoted string" ending in a comma,`

A simple regular expression such as:

`/([\s\w"']+),/`

Based on your initial requirement of "strings with quotes treated as literals" would capture.

The regex would give you a match group of:

```
[0]: This is a "quoted string" ending in a comma,

[1]: This is a "quoted string" ending in a comma
```

With `1`, obviously being the indices you want to save because when using groups `()`, `0` will always be the full match.

Edit: Ice76's answer on using explode to split your string is also a great (and much simpler) alternative.